# virtual tables and inheritance c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

i have a question regarding calling a function with virtual methods and multiple inheritence.
i have the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{};
class B:public A{};
class C:public B{};
class AA:public A{};
struct X
{
    void f(A*) { std::cout<< "X::f(A*)\n";}
    virtual void f(B*) { std::cout<< "X::f(B*)\n";}
    void f(C*) { std::cout<< "X::f(C*)\n";}
    virtual void f(C*) const { std::cout<< "const X::f(C*)\n";}
};
struct Y:public X {
    virtual void f(B*) { std::cout<< "Y::f(B*)\n";}
    void f(A*) { std::cout<< "Y::f(A*)\n";}
    virtual void f(C*) const { std::cout<< "const Y::f(C*)\n";}
};
int main() {   
    Y* y=new Y();
    y->f(new C);
}
```

I can't understand why this turns ambiguous and there are 2 candidates:

```
 Y::f(B*)
 Y::f(C*)
```

Comment: Where does it turn ambiguous?

Comment: when i try to compile the code.

Comment: What does it has to do with multiple inheritance? Each of your classes /structs inherits from a single class/struct.

Comment: @user3286882 [Here](http://ideone.com/1ZJ65r) your sample compiles fine?!?

Comment: if you compile with Wall it will present a warning

Comment: Looks like clang and icc shows an error while gcc shows a warning choosing the correct function afterall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an overloading function to be selected, it has to be the "best" at accepting each individual argument, including the implicit argument that becomes `this`. Best is defined in terms of the least conversions needed to convert the argument (in the caller) to the parameter (in the callee).

`virtual void f(C*) const` agrees perfectly with an argument of type `C*`, but the `const` qualifier at the end requires that `this` be converted from a non-const `Y*` to a `Y const *`. This is what the compiler is complaining about. If you cast

```
static_cast< Y const * >( y )->f(new C);
```

The problem goes away (although this isn't immediately illustrative since the extra qualification disqualifies the other overloads).

Note that all the overloads in `X` aren't even checked. The name resolution which finds all the overloads to be considered starts at the derived class and proceeds up the inheritance branches until it finds a matching name, *and then it stops*. To merge functions from multiple classes into one overload set, use a `using` declaration inside `Y`, `using X::f;`.

The actual solution to this problem is probably to introduce more matching overloads without `const` qualifiers at the end, so the `const` qualification of the calling pointer doesn't play such an unintuitive role.

Comment: but in order to use the Y::f(B*) it will need to convert the variable right? and for Y::f(C*) it is exact match. isn't this is the case here?

Comment: @user3286882 See edit; the `const` qualifier on `Y::f(C*) const` makes it not exact.

Comment: i was under the impression that non const to const (and opposite) is the same as exact match.

Comment: Actually it turned out rather educational, const qualifier can really make some things not so intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Your overload for C is the only const member function.
y is non const and all overloads of f are acceptable, hence the call is ambiguous.

Ways to resolve the ambiguity:

- Add a non const overload for C
- Make y const
- Make the overloads for A and B const

Answer (score 0):

void f(C*) { std::cout << "X::f(C*)\n"; } in base class 
is not visible due to name hiding.

use
`using X::f;`
in derived class, and it works as expected.